# Handling multiple variables in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, variables, for-loop

Here's issue I am learning python newly i want to use loop for generating inputs from user which are then operated for some custom function (say Lcm or squaring them and returning ) so how to perform code 
Consider

```
k,l=0,0

while l>=10:
    n_k=input("Enter")
    k=k+1
    l=l+1
    #Do something within for loop
    #here problem begins 
    #lets say i am dividing each variable by c which is here in for loop 
    for c in range(somevalue,0,-1):
```

now how should i operate the variables clearly i have no intention writting n_0%c ,n_1%c etc 

**Any Help???**

Comment: Please edit your code so it is properly visible in this page. Cut-and-paste from your text editor into this page's editor, then highlight your code and click the `{}` button at the top of this page's editor.

Comment: What "each variable"? I only see one input. I can't tell whether you're asking how to get multiple inputs in one string, how to get input multiple times, how to use a nested loop, or what.

Comment: just simply a way to do the programme i am not as experienced in programming just asking how should i do the (let me make it simple to understand) i want each input to be divided by 2 and result to be displayed with print@TigerhawkT3

Comment: Are you expecting the name of `n_k` to somehow change with every iteration, forcing you to somehow determine what it's called at any given point? Or something? I have no idea what the issue is here.

Comment: Sort of what you thought ,exactly i too  have no idea@TigerhawkT3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of n_k being a single variable i think you want n to be a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html). A list is just a bunch of variables stored together. For example the code:

```
n = [1, 4, 2]


print(n[0]) #0th element of the list
print(n[1]) #1st element of the list
print(n[2]) #2nd element of the list
```

outputs

1
4
2

the line n = [1, 4, 2] is just defining the list. The elements of the list are accessed using the n[index] notation.

In python you can also add elements to a list at any time using the append statement. To illustrate let's define an empty list and add some elements to it.

```
n = []
n.append(8)
```

Now if we try

```
print(n[0])
```

the code will print 8.

So let's say we wanted to square a list of numbers we receive from user input, we would write

```
n = []
k = 0

num_inputs = 10

while k < num_inputs:
    n.append(input("Enter:"))
    k = k + 1

k = 0
while k < num_inputs:
    print(n[k] * n[k])
    k = k + 1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: *list*, not *array*.

Comment: Thanks, just fixed it up then

Comment: can it handle all the inputs simultaneously like oprating each with if condition like if num1/2==0 and num2/2==0 like that

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but python does allow if statements of the form 

    if num1 == 0 and num2 == 0:

Comment: Well anyways It's the best answer i received so far , thanks

Comment: @versatile-vasu I think I get you now. Yes you can, the if statement will look like 
`if n[1] ==0 and n[2] ==0:` that is perfectly fine